# C# Dotnet core Console appsettings.json runtime reload

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a need where I may change appsettings.json while my Console app is running.
The code I am using to load appsettings.json is only loads the appsettings.json at startup and it never refreshes once the app is running. Can some one help me figure this out pls?

```
public IConfigurationRoot GetAppssetingsConfig()
    {
        
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                       .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                       .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                       .AddEnvironmentVariables();

        IConfigurationRoot configuration = builder.Build();
        configuration.Reload();

        return configuration;
    }
```

What I am expecting is that each time when I call the above function, it reads the appsettings.json at that time, however this is not happening.
Thanks for help

Comment: Which appsettings.json file are you editing at runtime?

Comment: not sure what you mean, there is one appsettings.json file in the program

Comment: If you're debugging, there is one in the project (the "master" copy if you will), and one that gets copied to the build directory.

Comment: Just realized what you meant..going to take a look...I have a feeling you are right...will get back here in few..Thanks

Comment: you are 100% right..DUHHHH...I was making change in VS while file being retrieved was in the debug folder..Thanks for waking me up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The configuration is monitoring (via `reloadOnChange: true`) the appsettings.json file in the current working directory (via `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`).

This is the build directory, if debugging.

Edits to the project's appsettings.json file (the "master" copy) won't be reflected while debugging. Instead, edit the copy in the build directory.

Comment: Thanks, I can not believe I had such brain activity loss...Thanks for waking me up..
I was running VS(not the first time but brain dead for some reasons) and making changes to the local file, while while debugging, file are transferred to Debug folder and of courses my changes to project file were not reflected. Again thanks for waking me up.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public IConfiguration GetAppssetingsConfig()
{
 return new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables()
            .Build();
 }
```

Comment: Thanks Serge, however that does not help, I have tried many variations, It seems like when app starts, it considers that as new session, however, any subsequent requests does not trigger reload as it probably thinks it is still the same session.

Comment: @user1063108 All my code is tested. this is working at my computer. What error do you have?

Comment: Absolutely no errors..I have watched breakpoints, it never reads new values from appsettings.json which are changed while program is running. it always have the values which are loaded when program started.

Comment: I guess it is because you are not supposed to change appsettings during runtime.

Comment: appsettings.json in a web app shows correct changes at run time, I think each request probably has its own scope, but in a console app, I somehow need to tell it to consider every call to this function as a new request/scope call...Anyways, thanks for taking your time. Hope some can see this and help.